# Insert rows from a table that are not present in the existing table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with the same schema/structure. I would like to add rows from the 2nd table that are not present in the 1st table.

For Example Table 1

```
UserID ProjectName Task        FirstName
1       ABC         Design     Sam 
2       DEF         Writing    John
```

Table 2

```
 UserID  ProjectName   Task   FirstName
    1       ABC           Design     Sam 
    2       DEF         Writing    John
    3       GHI         Presenting Tom
    1       LMN         Design     Sam
```

In this case the Composite Key is (UserID, ProjectName, Task). I would like to Insert the last two records from Table2 Into Table 1 since Table1 doesn't have those records.

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)

```
insert into table1(UserID, ProjectName, Task, FirstName) select UserID, 
ProjectName, Task, FirstName from table2 t2 left join table1 t1 on 
t2.ProjectName!=t1.ProjectName
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 (UserID, ProjectNam, Task, FirstName)
  SELECT UserID, ProjectNam, Task, FirstName
  FROM tbl2 WHERE project_name not in (select project_name from tbl1);
```